# Change/Update Field name in the NiFi Schema Text property Across various parallel flows

Tags: schema, etl, updates, apache-nifi

I have few identical parallel flows(as shown in screenshot). I have convertRecord in each of the identical flows and in the Record Reader I have used "Schema Text Field Property" as access strategy and specified the "Schema text". For Example:

```
   {
 "type": "record",

 "name": "AVLRecord0",

 "fields" : [

    {"name": "TimeOfDay", "type": "string", "logicalType":"timestamp-millis"},
    {"name":"Field1", "type": "double"},
    {"name":"Field2", "type": "double"},
    {"name":"Field3", "type": "double"},
    {"name": "Filename", "type": "string"}
]

}
```

Lets say the above schema I have used across various parallel flows ConvertRecord, and now I want to update one field name from **Field to Field_Name** so is there any way I can do it in one go across all the convert record Schema Text?

If I want to change/update one of the Field in the schema Text do I have to change/Update the field name in each processor manually? Or there is a global way that will change the field name across all the parallel flow I have?

Is there Any way that I can update the Schema Text across various processors In one go?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `Schema Text Field Property` so you need to change in **all ConvertRecord** processor manually.

***Try with this approach:***

In ConvertRecord processor use **Schema Access Strategy** as

```
Use Schema Name Property
```

Then set up **AvroSchemaRegistry** and define your schema by adding new property

[image]

I have added `sch` as schema.name and defined the avro schema.

After GetFile Processor use `UpdateAttribute` processor and add **`schema.name`** attribute(for ex: with value sch) to the flowfile.

- Now in reader controller service use the Schema Access strategy as `Use Schema Name Property and Schema Registry as`AvroSchemaRegistry` that has already setup.
  [image]

By following this way we are ***not defining schema*** on all **`ConvertRecord`** processors instead we are referring to **same schema** that defined in `AvroSchemaRegistry` in case if you want to change one field name it is easy to go into Registry and change the value.

**Flow:**

```
1.GetFile
2.UpdateAttribute //add schema.name attribute
3.ConvertRecord //define/use AvroSchemaRegistry and access strategy as schemaname property
..other processors
```

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/115311/convert-csv-to-json-avro-xml-using-convertrecord-p.html) link for more details regards to defining/using AvroSchemaRegistry.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. But then by this way I have to include multiple Schema.name in the 'AvroSchemaRegistry' as for all the convert-record processor I have different field names with only one field Repeating as common field across all Schema Text(Different schema in the Schema Text of each ConvertRecord). So By doing this approach I still have to update manually going into each Schema.Name property and update the field name? Is my understanding correct??

Comment: @shrads, Yes, as you are having **different schema's** for each `ConvertRecord` processors. I could suggest you can use either `1. one AvroSchemaRegistry and have different schema.name` attribute values (or) `2.Using UpdateAttribute -> Advanced usage` add rules if this file then add `schema.text` attribute with the schema to the flowfile. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/141774/how-to-generate-a-variable-under-conditions-for-an.html